# Best way to complete a cylinder from a segment

Tags: modeling

I have this section of a cylinder and I want to duplicate it around a central point to make a whole cylinder. What is the best way to do this?
[image]

Comment: You could either add a mirror modifier in X and Y axis, enter edit mode and duplicate it with Shift+D, or select one of the end vertex and spin it it with Alt+R. Then just extrude it upwards

Answer (score 1):

**Use Extrusion and the Mirror Modifier**

### Extrusion

If it is just a segment, first *Tab* into edit mode, rotate to front view (*Numpad 1*), key *E*, then *Z*, and drag the mouse downwards to the desired height for the cylinder.

### Mirror Modifier

With the cylinder selected, go to the *Object Modifiers* tab in the *Properties panel* and add a Mirror modifier. Set the settings as follows:

[image]

This will reflect the segment about the origin (the orange point with the green and red arrows coming from it).